# HEVC binary to MPEG 2TS

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a HEVC bit stream to MPEG-2 TS using ffmpeg. However I can't seem to perform the task without a wrapper such as mp4. Here is the command I was trying.

ffmpeg -i hevcBitstream.hevc -vcodec copy -acodec copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb output_file.ts

What seems to be the problem with this?.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/678897/extract-hevc-bitstream-with-ffmpeg

Comment: Another related, see comment with ffmpeg syntax: http://video.stackexchange.com/a/16643/1871

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me...

ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -vcodec copy -bsf:v hevc_mp4toannexb -f mpegts output_file.ts

Comment: Is really necessary add that filter? Also i tried it with an h264 stream that require the h264 version:
[mpegts @ 03fefac0] H.264 bitstream malformed, no startcode found, use the h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter (-bsf h264_
mp4toannexb)
If i do it on windows it says he can't find the hevc_mp4toannexb filter.